# Launch localhost in a browser from Android app without https://

Tags: android, webview, android-browser, nanohttpd

I have a nanoHttpd server in my app. After starting the server, if I manually go to the browser and type in `localhost:3000/index.html`, it works fine. But when I launch the browser from the app with `https://localhost:3000/index.html`. I see that it might be a problem with https://.

How can I handle this problem? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use `http` instead of `https`, since you have not configured SSL for your embedded server.

Comment: You're awesome. Thank you. This worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use `https` with servers configured for SSL. Your embedded server is not (and, so long as it only accepts requests from `localhost`, that's probably even OK). So, use `http` as the scheme, not `https`.